# Which is the fastest manner to the derive the conditional minimum value of an R data frame column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

Suppose we have this data frame:

```
> data
  ID Period_1 Values
1  1  2020-03     -5
2  1  2020-04     25
3  2  2020-01     35
4  2  2020-02     45
5  2  2020-03     55
6  2  2020-04     87
7  3  2020-02     10
8  3  2020-03     20
9  3  2020-04     30

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period_1 = c("2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04"),
    Values = c(-5, 25, 35, 45, 55, 87, 10, 20, 30)
  )
```

I would like to extract the minimum of "Values", but subject to the condition that a Period_1 condition is met (such as `Period_1 == "2020-04"`). My inclination is to use dplyr `group_by(Period_1) %>%` but I don't need the minimum for all Period_1 groupings, I just need the minimum of Values for the single specified period. The actual database I am working with has 2 million + rows and I suspect my abundant use of `group_by(...)` is slowing things down dramatically.

Other Stack Overflow (and Google, etc.) posts I reviewed also rely on `group_by`, maybe this is the quickest way to process this, I don't know, but I suspect not.

I tried the following but it didn't work: `data %>% select(where(data$Period_1 == "2020-04"))%>% min(data$Values, na.rm=TRUE)`, returning the message "Error: Can't convert a logical vector to function"

Processing speed-wise, which is the fastest way to extract a conditional minimum? Including by use of dplyr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing `dplyr::filter` with `dplyr::select`.
`select(where(condition))` selects columns based on a logical condition that is aplied to the whole vector/column, as in `select(where(is.numeric))`, which selects numeric columns.

To select rows that meet a condition, use `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
   filter(Period1 == "2020-04") %>%
   pull(Values) %>%
   min(na.rm = TRUE)

# OR with `summarise`

data %>%
   filter(Period1 == "2020-04") %>%
   summarise(min_Values = min(Values, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Obrigado! I forgot about that handy filter function! Of course...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R option (if you are looking for speed). We can subset the data, then get the minimum value for the third (i.e., `Values`) column.

```
min(data[data$Period_1 == "2020-04", ][,3], na.rm = TRUE)

# [1] 25
```

**Benchmark**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is another base R function, that follows the lines of [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70967231/8245406) but is faster for small to medium data sets. Then the 2nd base R and [GuedesBF `dplyr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70966465/8245406) solutions are timed and the timings plotted.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dtplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

f1 <- function(data, period){
  i <- data[["Period_1"]] == period
  min(data$Values[i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
f2 <- function(data, period){
  min(data[data$Period_1 == period, 3], na.rm = TRUE)
}
f3 <- function(data, period){
  data %>%
    filter(Period_1 == period) %>%
    pull(Values) %>%
    min(na.rm = TRUE)
}

funTest <- function(n, X = data, period = "2020-04"){
  Y <- as.data.table(X)
  out <- lapply(seq.int(n), function(k){
    y <- X
    y2 <- Y
    for(i in seq.int(k)) y <- rbind(y, y)
    for(i in seq.int(k)) y2 <- rbind(y2, y2)
    mb <- microbenchmark(
      base_Rui = f1(y, period),
      base_Andrew = f2(y, period),
      dplyr_GuedesBF = f3(y, period),
      dtplyr_GuedesBF = f3(y2, period)
    )
    mb$nrow <- nrow(y)
    aggregate(time ~ expr + nrow, mb, median)
  })
  do.call(rbind, out)
}

timings <- funTest(20)

ggplot(timings, aes(nrow, time, color = expr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Upvoated! You can try `with(data, min(Values[Period_1 == period], na.rm = TRUE))`, which might be a bit faster

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to give the complete code a re-think, there are 2mm+ rows of data and sorting/grouping via dplyr is very slow. Seems that by moving some of the functions to Base R will speed things up

Comment: Hi, @Rui Barradas. I just ran your benchmarking function with a `dtplyr` solution. Would you mind if I edited your question and plot to include a 4th solution? All the structure from your original question would remain unchanged

Comment: @GuedesBF Can you post the function? I'll be glad to edit the answer.

Comment: `library(dtplyr);

f4 <- function(data, period){
        data %>%
                lazy_dt() %>%
                filter(Period_1 == period) %>%
                pull(Values) %>%
                min(na.rm = TRUE) %>%
                as_tibble()
}
`

Comment: Nice to see `dtplyr` does not seem to be any more efficient than `dplyr` for this simple operation. Disclaimer: I am not much of a `data.table` specialist, I know there is more to `data.table` and `dtplyr` than what we see here.

Comment: @GuedesBF To coerce the data to `data.table` in the function will take time, in my edit I coerce it before the function call, call the very same `f3` and the S3 methods dispatching takes care of calling the data.table methods for the `dplyr` functions.

Comment: Oh, I see. So data.table methods really scale better than dplyr. A bit out of my league though, it may take me a while to fully grasp these concepts. Thank you Rui.